# Python3 Try with multiple Except not working (Django)

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, try-catch, except

I've got the following function

```
question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
try:
    selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
    return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
        'question': question,
        'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
    })
else:
    selected_choice.votes += 1
    selected_choice.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id,)))
```

When I do an empty POST, I get a yellow error page saying

```
name 'Choice' is not defined. Exception Type:   NameError"
```

I changed the except to the following:

```
except KeyError:
```

Now it works, but I would still like to have the  Choice.DoesNotExist exception beeing cought. I'd like to keep it in one line as well. What's the problem here?

EDIT:
I forgot the include for "Choice", stupid me. Problem solved.

Comment: Exactly what it says: you haven't defined Choice. Presumably you forgot to import it in your view

Comment: Whops, you are right, I forgot the include. Stupid me.